# remove duplicates from comma separated string

Tags: php, csv

Is there a better (faster) solution to remove duplicates from a comma separated string?

```
public function d($dep) { 
    if (strpos($dep,',') !== false) {
        $nd = explode(',',$dep);
        $oa = array_unique($nd);
        $nx = (count($oa) > 1) ? implode(",",$oa) : $oa[0];
    }
    else {
        $nx = $dep;
    }

    return $nx;
}
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: Well, for one thing, removing line breaks won't make it run faster...

Comment: You know you're allowed to use meaningful variable names, or do you just like to make life harder for yourself?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use the uniqueness of array keys:

```
function d($dep) {
    return implode(',', array_keys(array_flip(explode(',', $dep))));
}
```

[`array_flip`](http://php.net/array_flip) swaps the key-value association, so the values become the keys and vice versa. This will automatically eliminate duplicates. Its runtime complexity is O(*n*).

Answer (score 18):

Try just this:

```
$uniqueDep = implode(',', array_unique(explode(',', $dep)));
```

Comment: Note that `array_unique` sorts the values before removing duplicates. That’s O(n·log n).

Comment: I get 30 points for a 10-second answer when many others have posted the same thing too. Yet, I get fewer than 30 points for a 10-minute answer that is unique.

Comment: Note that my string of functions is 10 characters shorter, and the functions used make the meaning very clear. Okay, so what is with people and their O(nlogn)? I am in first year and we've only touched on the subject, but from what I can see visually, O(nlogn) looks pretty damn close to O(n). I do not see the motivation to care about the distinction.

Comment: @erisco: The question was if there is a better (faster) solution. And when talking about speed of algorithms, you should mention the runtime complexity. Because that is *the* key for an abstract asymptotic runtime analysis. And your solution is asymptotically slower than mine due to the additionally sorting.

Comment: Faster is subjective; I presume he meant with less busywork, or less code.

Comment: @erisco: If by faster you mean it takes less time, then yes. There absolutely are additional factors that can adulterate the measurements. The key here is: [To go faster, do less.](http://asserttrue.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-write-fast-code.html) But having a shorter code doesn’t mean it’s faster.

Comment: You should consider **trim** to make sure that leading and trailing spaces with commas don't make some elements repeat.

Comment: Faster in that there is less code to type and less code to read. Also, I ran a benchmark and mistyped a variable name, with error reporting somehow turned off, and experienced oddly linear behavior because I was operating on an empty array. D'oh. Yes, seems as though the flip is hip.

Comment: @erisco: I have never heard that when talking about the speed of an algorithm that one would refer to the time to write or read the code. And even if so it’s a bad measurement. Just think of the example of searching for a particular value in a sorted array: A linear search algorithm might be short and concise but a binary search algorithm would outrank it runtime complexity.

Answer (score 5):

I would probably use the same kind of idea that what you posted ; but I think you can remove your two conditions, to use only this :

```
$exploded = explode(',', $str);
$unique = array_unique($exploded);
$imploded = implode(',', $unique);
var_dump($imploded);
```

I've tested it with those three strings, and it seems to work in each case :

```
$str = 'a,b,c,d,a,c,e,f';
$str = 'a,a';
$str = 'a';
```

Notes :

- Using [`explode`](http://fr.php.net/explode) on a string that doesn't contain the delimiter will return an array with one element -- *your test with strpos is not necessary.*
- And using [`implode`](http://fr.php.net/implode) on an array with only one element will work too (not adding any delimiter) -- *your test with the ternary operator is not necessary either.*

Of course, you can also remove the variables, and use only one line :

```
$result = implode(',', array_unique(explode(',', $str)));
```

Not sure it's easier to understand that way, though...

Answer (score 2):

Many many thanks guys. Finally, we have two solutions (Pascal and Ericso gave the same solution) here and the question became which one is faster. To be honest, by faster, I meant what executes faster and if I take words of Gumbo, I get the combined functions of `array_keys` and `array_flip` is faster than `array_unique`. Because, the two other functions, `implode` and `explode` are same.

```
return implode(',', array_unique(explode(',', $dep)));
return implode(',', array_keys(array_flip(explode(',', $dep))));
```

Finally I gave 1 up to all three ad many thanks that can't be measured / seen. I agree that either of the three solutions can be expected, but then took the answer of Gumbo believing that `array_keys(array_flip())` is faster to execute than `array_unique()` in the given context.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = implode(',',array_unique(explode(',', $str)));
```