# How to remove repeated substrings from a string

Tags: php

I have a string like this:

> 'spain,france,spain,germany,france,spain'

need to have only unique substrings

> 'spain,france,germany'

the only way I could think of was this converting to an array and back:

```
$countries = "spain,france,spain,germany,france,spain";
$country = implode( ",", array_unique( explode( ",", $countries ) ) );
```

Another/correct way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove duplicates from comma separated string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134176/remove-duplicates-from-comma-separated-string)

Comment: only if a source string may  contain space after comma, you will need other  solution

Comment: @splash58 the source string may have spaces after comma, will the other solution be better/faster?

Answer (score 0):

I think your way to do this is good. 
But you need to watchout for **spaces** between comma and word. To do this just add: 
`$countries = str_replace(' ', '', $countries);`

If you expect **whitespaces** to be there aswell you should remove them using regular expressions:
`$countries = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $countries);`

If you don't know the difference between **space** and **whitespace**:

- Space is just regular space character between other characters
- Whitespace can be space, tabulation, new line etc.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php)

Comment: Or using "map('trim',  explode())" after explode

Comment: if it will be `Great Britain,` ?