# remove duplicates from comma separated string when there are spaces in the elements

Tags: php

I have found an answer on this question: [remove duplicates from comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134176/remove-duplicates-from-comma-separated-string)
however it doesn't answer what would be the best way to removes duplicates when there are spaces within the strings and/or spaces after each delimiter.

So I have this string:

`Yogurt (Milk), Strawberries (11%), Sugar, Water, Stabilisers: Pectins, Guar Gum, Flavourings, Acidity Regulator: Citric Acid, Yogurt (Milk), Peach (9%), Sugar, Water, Apricot (3%), Stabilisers: Pectins, Guar Gum, Acidity Regulator: Citric Acid, Flavourings`

to remove the duplicates I have used this code:

```
$str = implode(',',array_unique(explode(',', $str)));
```

but its not working as the first element in the string doesn't have a space at the beginning.

what would be the best way to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

This might be help you:

```
    $str = "Yogurt (Milk), Strawberries (11%), Sugar, Water, Stabilisers: Pectins, Guar Gum, Flavourings, Acidity Regulator: Citric Acid, Yogurt (Milk), Peach (9%), Sugar, Water, Apricot (3%), Stabilisers: Pectins, Guar Gum, Acidity Regulator: Citric Acid, Flavourings";

    $new_str = array_unique(array_map('trim', explode(',', $str)));
    $string = implode(',', $new_str);

    echo $string;
```

You need to trim whitespace and remove duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

if there is always a space character after each comma, you can include the space character in the explode/implode functions

```
$str = implode(', ',array_unique(explode(', ', $str)));
```

otherwise you have to trim spaces, like the other answer suggests